# Pass request.user to dispatch method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

**Env:** Python 3.6, Django 3.0, DRF 3.11, JWT Authorization

Hello everybody.

I have a simple class in my API where I want to check user permissions in each method `get`, `post` etc. I planned to check user privileges at dispatch but it doesn't work. Simplify code, my current class looks more or less like this:

```
class ExampleClassName(APIView):
    can_do_sth = False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.user)  # Here is AnonymousUser
        if request.user.username == "GreatGatsby":
            self.can_do_sth = True
        return super(ExampleClassName, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        print(request.user)  # Here is correctly Logged user
        if self.can_do_sth:
            return Response("You can do it")
        return Response("You can't")

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.user)  # Here is correctly Logged user
        if self.can_do_sth:
            return Response("You can do it")
        return Response("You can't")
```

How can I pass `request.user` to dispatch method?

Answer (score 4):

ok solved

`initialize_request` - is doing what I expected. so right dispatch should be:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    req = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
    print(req.user)  # Now I have logged user data
    if req.user.username == "GreatGatsby":
        self.can_do_sth = True
    return super(ExampleClassName, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Task closed unless you have any other idea how to do it in different way. If you do - please share :)